# Secure php files so only I can execute them

Tags: php, security

Currently I have a bit of a 'different' set-up. My main files are on server1; this server simply delivers the content through php and mysql. But that's just the front end. In the back, on server2 (homeserver), are alot of different scripts doing various things that could not be done on server1, since it's a shared host and thus resources are limited.

This setup works great. If server2 loses power or something the site won't be updated, but what's there is still available, and it can just catch up once back online. But here's the problem; all scripts on the homeserver are wide open for everyone to execute. As an example, my database-syncing script;

Server1 detects it's databases hasn't been synced up with the one on server2, so it initiates the syncing script.

```
<?php
//This initiates the script on server2, which then dumps it's database into a .sql file
file_get_contents('http://server2.x.com/backup/backup_mysql.php');
//This reads out and saves said database file locally for processing
$myresult2 = file_get_contents('http://server2.x.com/backup/backups/db-backup.sql');
file_put_contents_atomic("backups/db-backup.sql", $myresult2);
//This will delete the backup file from server2
$deleteurl = 'http://server2.x.com/backup/backup_mysql.php?delete=true';
$myresult3 = file_get_contents($deleteurl);
//This initiates bigdump for processing the sql file
include_once('bigdump.php');
?>
```

As you can see, this opens up some obvious security flaws. *backup_mysql.php* can be used by anyone who knows the address to server2 and even once that's fixed, someone who monitors the /backup folder can retrieve the sql backup before my script deletes it again.

How do I prevent all this from happening?

Comment: Look into using HTTP authentication to prevent access to everything published by server 2. It should be the easiest approach.

Comment: @Jon as stated in the example, server1 does stuff like file_get_contents($url); - I reckon that with authentication this would become something like `http://user:pass@server2.x.com/blalba.php` - Wouldn't a smart user be able to intercept that link and thus obtain my username and password?

Comment: @natli: A smart someone with access to either your source code or your network packets could, but a user doesn't fall into this category. Also, you could prevent the packet sniffing scenario by switching to HTTPS. You can also move to custom authentication if you find HTTP auth insufficient. At the end of the day, you have two parties exchanging sensitive information through HTTP(S). If it's secure enough for banks, it should be secure enough for you.

Comment: @Jon HTTPS would be too expensive for this project (you need a certificate, right?) but from what I hear, just authentication should do the trick considering it's not extremely sensitive data being moved around.

Comment: @natli: You can create the certificates yourself and have your programs recognize them as valid (I have done this using `curl`). Commercial SSL certificates are only needed if you need them to be recognized as valid by the rest of the world as well.

Comment: @Jon I'll check it out, thanks! Too bad you didn't respond in a regular "answer" because now I can't pick it :o

Comment: @natli: I didn't intend to write a full answer either at that point :) Anyway, I 've just adapted the above to a regular answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into using HTTP authentication to prevent access to everything published by server 2. This way you 'd be able to lock everyone else out of server 2 with minimum hassle.

With HTTP auth in place, your `file_get_contents` calls would need to change to include the credentials, for example

```
file_get_contents(http://user:pass@server2.example.com/data.php);
```

If you are worried that someone might sniff the credentials from the network, then you can also move to HTTPS. Since both the server the only user will be your own applications, you can create the certificates yourself and make your scripts accept them as valid.

Comment: Going for this + IP restriction. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Apache2 webserver directves to deny access to certain locations from all IPs except your own.

Comment: I use lighttpd but yeah that has a similar function. Problem is, the server's IP will be used and not my own. So I believe some smart person can alter the $_GET values to attempt SQL injection and whatnot, or isn't that the case?

Comment: Well yes smart (and evil!) people can hack Sony, Citibank and whatnot. There are common security vulnerabilities, eg SQL injection which you can easily prevent using proper coding. Also, understanding and hardening the permissions of web directories will prevent attacks.

Comment: Good point. I guess I'll go for both IP restriction and HTTP auth. Should be good enough for a small project like this :D

Answer (score 1):

You can protect your files or folders through `.htaccess`:

[Password protecting your pages with htaccess](http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/)

Comment: lighttpd doesn't support htacces unfortunately, and I stand by it because it has been way faster than apache2 ever was.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution besides .htaccess:

```
server1/index.php
server1/config.php
server2/index.php
```

Lets say you dont want people accessing config, use the `define` function. Define a unique name and check if it's defined in the config.php file before setting variables / methods.

Comment: Never heard of define before, I will have to investigate further because I haven't got a clue what to do with just that info. Thanks for your answer, I'm going to look in to it.

Comment: `define('natli_safe');` use that in server2/index.php. and `if (defined('natli_safe'))` in server1/config.php. I'm not sure if this solution works with file_get_contents, it's unsafe to load files from remote servers.

Comment: file_get_contents does not load the actual php file, it just loads it's output. You can look at it as php "visiting" the website like a normal user would. In this case there is no output, but the main idea is that the script gets executed behind the scenes. file_get_contents would not be able to detect 'natli_safe' is defined.

Comment: What this technique does is *restrict the entry points to the application for everyone*. Since you will be using the same entry points as J. Random Hacker, this doesn't buy you anything in this scenario.